# Issue parsing JSON with JQuery

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization

I am trying to parse a JSON object passed from a WCF Service, here is the Response the service gives

```
[
 {
   "Caption": "Hello",
   "CityState": "Seattle",
   "URL": "Test"
 },
 {
   "Caption": "World",
   "CityState": "Chicago",
   "URL": "Test"
 },
 {
    "Caption": "Hello",
    "CityState": "New York",
    "URL": "Test"
 }
]
```

Here is the WCF Code to create the object

```
///Custom Object has 3 string properties
List<OW_CompanyACSearch> search = new List<OW_CompanyACSearch>();

  DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<OW_CompanyACSearch>));
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, search);
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
```

and here is the JQuery that I am trying to make work

```
    source: function (request, response) {
            j$.ajax({
                url:"testservice.svc",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    Search: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    response(j$.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.Caption,
                            value: item.Caption,
                            URL: item.URL,
                            CityState: item.CityState
                        }

                    }));
                }
            });
        }
```

The issue that I am having is that when I fall into the return to parse the members on the object, none of the properties are defined. If I drill down into the object, it seems that it is treating object as one long string, so index[0] would be "[" and so on.

I have read all over and I have tried every option that I have seen and I still get this issue. I am not sure if I am serializing or parsing incorrectly, but any help would be appreciated.

Also, not sure if it matters, but the binding on the WCF is webHttpBinding

Comment: it IS coming back as a string, isn't it? you need to call JSON.parse() on it first to convert the response to a JSON object I believe.

Comment: Another option would be to call `data = j$.parseJSON(data);` right before the part with `response(j$.map(data, ...`

Comment: @jonhopkins when I add the line above the response, data becomes a null object. thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Wow this was awesome, come to find out that data was just a wrapper for the JSON object, and there was a property named "d" that was the actual object.

So this

```
 data = j$.parseJSON(data.d);
```

filled data with the object, and I could move forward.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` object should already be a variable array that contains your data at the properties as named by the JSON. You should be able to do something like this:

```
source: function (request, response) {
        j$.ajax({
            url:"testservice.svc",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                Search: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data[0].Caption);
            }
        });
    }
```

To verify the object structure.

Comment: that is the issue, the data object coming back is not indexablem, so data[0] is null

Comment: Make sure that the testservice.svc's response type is the JSON MIME type of "application/json". This is the only thing that can be going wrong. since dataType: "json" tells jQuery to parse the data as a JSON object.

Comment: how exactly do I do that? Is there a property I need to set? I figured returning the encoded string is enough.

Comment: @IsaacLevin [this](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/) link might help you out.